# Using $.each() within $.getJSON

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, each, getjson

This is for a jQuery Mobile app using version 1.0.1.

I'm trying to get data from my `getmovies.php` file, which outputs JSON, to use in a jQuery function which appends the data to an unordered list on my HTML page.

My HTML page displays correctly, but the getMoviesList() function does not append any list items, so the content area is left blank.

My guess is that there is something wrong with my $.each() function. I'm more comfortable with PHP, but trying to get more familiar with jQuery and JSON for moving data around within jQuery Mobile apps.

`getmovies.php` outputs **JSON** as follows:

```
{"items":[
{"movieID":"65086","title":"The Woman in Black","poster":"\/kArMj2qsOnpxBCpSa3RQ0XemUiX.jpg"},
{"movieID":"76726","title":"Chronicle","poster":"\/853mMoSc5d6CH8uAV9Yq0iHfjor.jpg"}
]}
```

My **Javascript** is as follows:

```
var serviceURL = "http://mydomain.com/app3/services/";

var movies;

$('#moviesPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
  getMoviesList();
});

function getMoviesList() {
  $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getmovies.php', function(data) {
    $('#moviesList li').remove();
    movies = data.items;
    $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {
      $('#moviesList').append('<li><a href="movie-details.html?movieID=' + movie.movieID + '">' +
      '<img src="posters/' + movie.poster + '"/>' +
      '<h4>' + movie.title + '</h4>' +
      '<p>Other details...</p>' +
      '</a></li>');
    });
    $('#movieList').listview('refresh');
  });
}
```

My **HTML** looks like this:

```
<div id="moviesPage" data-role="page">

  <div data-role="content">

    <ul id="moviesList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"></ul>

  </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

I'm trying to modify the following example app to meet my needs: http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Do you get data when you run `console.log(movie)` on the first line of the each?

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your comment. I'm actually not sure how to use `console.log()`. I'm working with my files within my code editor and uploading them to my server to test.

Comment: Add that line and then when you run the page use http://getfirebug.com/ to view javascript data and errors or send me the link

Comment: @Adam Thanks for your help! The link is http://stay4credits.com/app3, then click 'Should I stay for credits?' link. I didn't notice any errors in firebug.

Comment: In firebug you can see that the getJson isn't running, meaning that the function isn't firing so the lines `$('#moviesPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) { getMoviesList(); });` is not binding that page to running that function correctly.

Comment: @Adam Thanks for helping me track down the issue. The example app I was using was based on an older version of jQuery mobile. I changed the code you referenced in your last comment to `$( document ).delegate("#moviesPage", "pageinit", function() {...` and it is pulling in the data now. I just need to fix the `listview('refresh')`, which I already have a solution for. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if your JSON output is valid: verify here [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com)

Change your bind event to this and see if it's working.

```
$('#moviesPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) {
    getMoviesList();
});
```

to this

```
$('#moviesPage').live('pageshow', function(event) { //or 'pagecreate'
    getMoviesList();
});
```

As i can see, the rest of JS code is ok!
Try this and see if it's working. As i know, it should! This is the method i use on my mobile app and works very well.

Comment: Thanks! This does work. Do you know how to get the listview to populate with the data before loading the page? I am currently using `pagebeforecreate`, but the page has the default load animation before the page changes, but then the page is blank until the listview data is retrieved. I would like for the listview to be populated as soon as the default page-change loading animation is finished.

Comment: You could try putting the loading symbol on start of live event. "$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();" and then hide it after your json call with "$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();". This way, at least when your data is loading, it shows a loading symbol.

Answer (score 1):

With Adam's help I was able to narrow down the issue.

If you are using the "Sample Application using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap" by Christophe Coenraets (http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/) and are using jQuery Mobile higher than 1.0rc1, you will probably need to replace the following code in your javascript from:

```
$('#employeeListPage').bind('pageinit', function(event) { getEmployeeList(); });
```

to:

```
$( document ).delegate("#employeeListPage", "pageinit", function() { getEmployeeList(); });
```

The reason for this is explained in the jQuery Mobile docs at the following link under **pageCreate = DOM ready**:http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html.

I hope this helps anyone that runs into the same issue trying to use this great sample app.